# XQuery returns no results when selecting node attribute

Tags: regex, xml, xpath, xquery, basex

Loaded an XML database around 1 GB into BaseX and got stuck after reading some tutorials. Here's a sample document:

```
<GRUPO-DE-PESQUISA xmlns="http://www.cnpq.br/lmpl/2002/XSD/Grupo" NRO-ID-GRUPO="0002998250206250" ESTRATIFICACAO="" FORMATO-HORA-ATUALIZACAO="HHMMSS" HORA-ATUALIZACAO="092500" FORMATO-DATA-ATUALIZACAO="DDMMAAAA" DATA-ATUALIZACAO="08122016" SISTEMA-ORIGEM-XML="Lattes Extrator">
  <IDENTIFICACAO-DO-GRUPO NRO-ID-CNPQ-INSTITUICAO="4043451737504096" CODIGO-AREA-PREDOMINANTE="80200001" NOME-DA-UNIDADE="" NOME-DO-ORGAO="Colégio Pedro II" FLAG-INSTITUICAO-DE-ENSINO="" FLAG-AGENCIA-FOMENTO="N" SIGLA-DO-PAIS-DA-INSTITUICAO="BRA" NOME-DO-PAIS-DA-INSTITUICAO="BRA" UF-DA-INSTITUICAO="RJ" SIGLA-DA-INSTITUICAO="CP II" NOME-DA-INSTITUICAO="Colégio Pedro II" AREA-PREDOMINANTE="Letras" GRANDE-AREA-PREDOMINANTE="Lingüística, Letras e Artes" ANO-DE-CRIACAO="2015" NOME-DO-GRUPO=" LITESCOLA - Literatura e outras linguagens na Escola Básica: letramento literário e formação continuada do professor">
    <LIDERES>
      <PRIMEIRO-LIDER NRO-ID-CNPQ="3361551338665953" PAIS-DE-NASCIMENTO="BRA" NACIONALIDADE="B" NOME-COMPLETO="Ana Cristina Coutinho Viegas"/>
      <SEGUNDO-LIDER NRO-ID-CNPQ="6282140310430273" PAIS-DE-NASCIMENTO="BRA" NACIONALIDADE="B" NOME-COMPLETO="Márcio Vinícius do Rosário Hilário"/>
    </LIDERES>
</IDENTIFICACAO-DO-GRUPO>
</GRUPO-DE-PESQUISA>
```

I'd like to get the value for `@NRO-ID-GRUPO` whenever `@NOME-DO-GRUPO` contains `literatura`:

```
data(//IDENTIFICACAO-DO-GRUPO[matches(@NOME-DO-GRUPO,'^literatura','i')]/@NRO-ID-GRUPO)
```

No results were returned for the query above. What could I be missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be a caps issue? `Literatura` vs. `literatura`?

Comment: Replaced with uppercase L, didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the elements you are trying to select are namespaced by  `xmlns="http://www.cnpq.br/lmpl/2002/XSD/Grupo"`. You will need to declare that namespace and assign it a prefix in the prolog of your XQuery module:

```
declare namespace grupo = "http://www.cnpq.br/lmpl/2002/XSD/Grupo"
```

And in your expression, refer to the elements using the prefix:

```
//grupo:IDENTIFICACAO-DO-GRUPO
```

Next, the use of the carat in your regular expression forces the text `literatura` only to match if it appears at the beginning of a string:

```
matches(@NOME-DO-GRUPO,'^literatura','i')
```

If you want to match on word boundaries to prevent substring matching you can use `(^|\s)`, but you may also want to add a trailing boundary:

```
matches(@NOME-DO-GRUPO,'(^|\s)literatura($|\s)','i')
```

Also, depending on how much speed is important in your application, it might be worth testing the relative performance in BaseX of regular expression matching vs tokenizing, and compare the above expression to:

```
tokenize(lower-case(@NOME-DO-GRUPO), '\s') = 'literatura'
```

Comment: Tried rewriting as `data(//IDENTIFICACAO-DO-GRUPO[matches(@NOME-DO-GRUPO,'(^|\s)literatura($|\s)','i')]/@NRO-ID-GRUPO)`, still no hits. Tried using uppercase L too, still no hits.

Comment: You must select the elements using the proper namespace or using a wildcard prefix. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi. So I changed the expression to the following:
`declare namespace grupo = "http://www.cnpq.br/lmpl/2002/XSD/Grupo";
//grupo:IDENTIFICACAO-DO-GRUPO[contains(@NOME-DO-GRUPO,'Literatura')]
//@NOME-DO-GRUPO,//@NRO-ID-GRUPO`
It returns all existing id numbers, instead of only the ones that contains "Literatura"

Comment: Solved it, should have used a pipe symbol:
`declare namespace grupo = "http://www.cnpq.br/lmpl/2002/XSD/Grupo"; //grupo:IDENTIFICACAO-DO-GRUPO[contains(@NOME-DO-GRUPO,'Lite‌​ratura')] data(//@NOME-DO-GRUPO | //@NRO-ID-GRUPO)`
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @wlwy If this answered your question, click the green check to the left of the answer to accept it.